# ORACLE Maximum number

Tags: oracle

If I declare in oracle a column as a number , What will be the maximum number it can be stored ?
Based on documentation:

> Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10(raised)-130 to 9.99...9 x 10(raised)125 with up
>   to 38 significant digits

10(raised)125 is a very big number which has more than 38 digits. Will it not be stored ? If a number greater than 38 digits is stored, it will fail ? , will it save but when queried will lose precision ?

Thanks

Comment: I stress the word "significant" from the documentation

Answer (score 1):

From [`Oracle Doc`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209)

> Positive numbers in the range 1 x 10^130 to 9.99...9 x 10^125 with up
>   to 38 significant digits Negative numbers from -1 x 10^130 to
>   9.99...99 x 10^125 with up to 38 significant digits

Test

```
create table tbl(clm number);
insert into tbl select power(10, -130) from dual;
insert into tbl select 9.9999*power(10, 125) from dual;
insert into tbl select 0.12345678912345678912345678912345678912123456 from dual;
insert into tbl select -1*power(10, -130) from dual;
select clm from tbl;
select to_char(clm) from tbl;
```

OutPut

```
1.000000000000000000000000000000000E-130
9.999900000000000000000000000000000E+125
.123456789123456789123456789123456789121
-1.00000000000000000000000000000000E-130
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers (datatype **NUMBER**) are stored using [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

i.e. 1000000 as 1 * 10^6 i.e. you store only 1 (mantissa) and 6 (exponent)

```
select VSIZE(1000000), VSIZE(1000001) from dual;

 VSIZE(1000000) VSIZE(1000001)
 -------------- --------------
              2              5
```

For the first number you need only 1 byte for mantissa, for the second 4 bytes (2 digist per byte).

So using **NUMBER** you will not get an exception while starting to loose precision.

```
 select power(2,136) from dual;
 87112285931760246646623899502532662132700
```

This number not exact and "filled" with zeroes (exponent). This may or may not be harmfull - consider e.g. the MOD function:

```
 select mod(power(2,136),2) from dual;
 -100
```

If you want to controll the precision exactly use e.g. datatype **NUMBER(38,0)**

```
 select cast(power(2,136) as NUMBER(38,0)) from dual;

 ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```